# Detect when "add icon to home screen" is enabled?

Tags: android, settings, android-launcher

Is it possible, in Android, to programmatically detect in Java when "Add icon to home screen" has been enabled, so I can know that my app should not attempt to add an icon itself on first run?

[image: add icon home screen android]

Comment: The people who have that unchecked specifically don't want an icon - why would you want to add an icon in those cases either?

Comment: Not all Android devices have this setting available, so I'd like to know which do and which do not, and for those that do, whether it's enabled or not. If it is enabled, I do not want my code to run, and if it is not present at all as an option on Android, I would like my code to run.